# Nested IF statement with multiple outcomes over an array of 168000+ rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that contains a bunch of information dummy sheet available here: [SO | Demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Oh1vwfuPmx-MwkeGdCcgEyfkD2uo0vh5tahvA7x0TU/edit?usp=sharing)

Basically, I need Column M to populate (preferably as an arrayformula or similar function as there is a LOT of rows for it to parse) according to the rules below (also in the sheet, with rows colour coded to match). I tried some nested IF formulas but tripped over myself a bunch of times. So if anyone could help that would be amazeballs.

```
Criteria:   
IF -> H2:H = BLANK AND L2:L = BLANK THEN "Active"   
IF -> H2:H = "Yes" AND L2:L = Date in the Future THEN "Active"   
IF -> H2:H = BLANK AND L2:L = Date in the Past THEN "Not Active"  
IF -> H2:H = "Yes" AND L2:L = BLANK THEN "Active"
```

Comment: There's not a huge amount of formulas that works exclusively in one or the other, which is why I tagged both. Sorry if that's not the ok thing to do.

Comment: It does not seem to matter what is in H.  It seems that the difference is that if L is in the past it is not active, otherwise it is active.  So `=IF(L2:L<TODAY(),"Not Active","Active")` should do what you want, unless you have not given all the information we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic of your rules can be simplified quite a bit...  try to test this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(LOOKUP(TO_TEXT(H2:H&L2:L),{"0","Yes"},{"Not",""}))&"Active")
```

Comment: Only thing is that it is showing "Active" for people that have a Date of 31/08/2021, which should come back as "Not Active"

Comment: I thought that was only true if H is blank? @sL8t7

Comment: Yeah, looks like an oversight on my part! If H is not blank and L is a date in the past, then "Not Active"

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably write a simple custom function instead using the standard formulas here, but here it is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((H2:H="")*(L2:L=""),"Active",
   IF((H2:H="Yes")*(L2:L>TODAY()),"Active",
   IF((H2:H="")*(L2:L<TODAY()),"Not Active",
   IF((H2:H="Yes")*(L2:L=""),"Active",""),""),""),"")
```